# Angular show custom content (arrows) on overflow after content comes remotely

Tags: javascript, angular, scroll, angular2-changedetection

I have a div which has data coming in remotely from a subscribed service
`overflow-y` is set to *scroll* 
I have to put custom arrows when the overflow happens and user can click, 
 and I have a scroll method with a `#templateRef` which will handle manual scrolling

 template and ts look like below

```js
@ViewChild('scrollContent') scrollContent: ElementRef
  ptivate data
  private overflow: boolean = false
  
  constructor (private service: DataService, private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
  
  ngOnInit () {
    this.service.subscribe(data => {
    this.data = data
    this.isOverflow()
    })
    
    isOverFlow () {
      if (this.scrollContent.nativeElement.scrollHeight > this.scrollContent.nativeElement.clientHeight) {
            this.overflow = true
      } else {
            this.overflow = false
      }
    }
  }
```

```html
<div *ngIf="overflow"  (click)="scroll($event,'up')">
  <div class="uparrow">
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="content" #scrollContent>
  <!-- 
  Iterate or display data thus changing the content of div and might cause 
  overflow-y
  -->
 </div>
 
 <div *ngIf="overflow"  (click)="scroll($event,'down')">
   <div class="downarrow">
   </div>
 </div>
```

But `isOverflow()` returns `false` and  *console.log* runs before and prints *false* before the view is updated 
I tried some `changeDetectionMethods` like `cdr.detectChanges()` and `markForChange()` did not have any luck with it.

I can manually trigger a `setTimeOut` and that might work but I am looking for angular specific answer

P.S. I have tried some *life-cycle-hooks* too but obviously you don't want them to trigger like 1000 times a second so I have avoided using some of them unless I am missing one which solves this purpose and gets called exactly *once* for example `ngAfterViewChecked()` is not performant at all as it keeps getting called again and again

***Angular version is 5.2.10***

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried ngAfterViewInit()?

Comment: yes infact I am doing it just in case if the data is ready so it works correctly but gets called only at the time of component init 
I have something like 
`ngAfterViewInit () {
    this.isOverflow()
    this.cdr.detectChanges()
  }`
I mean works correctly only if the data is there does not work if component is already there and data comes in later

Comment: Are you sure it is a timing/change detection issue? You mentioned a timeout, you could do that to test if it is a timing/change detection issue.

Comment: yes so I tried 2 things 
after receiving data I called `cdr.detectChanges()` which happens to work in `ngAfterViewInit` but did not work in this case 
and second I added `setTimeOut(()=> this.isOverflow(), 50)` and it worked
so definitely it is a timing/change detection issue but `setTimeOut` looks kinda hacky was wondering if Angular has something for it

Comment: I agree that you should not use setTimeout. But it is a good way to confirm if it is a timing issue.

Comment: @Anuj, use setTimeout id perfectly if you need give a breath to Angular, it say: 'paint all and, after paint all, calculate the new value', but you can use `setTimeOut(()=> this.isOverflow())` -remove the milliseconds, it's not necesary-

Comment: @Eliseo yeah I can omit the milliseconds as setTimeOut will automatically be executed in next execution context anyway ... 
but yeah I think that's the only solution for now I reckon ?